# Docker-compose volume changed update slowly (how to fix)

Tags: php, laravel-5, docker-compose

I build a small Laravel website using docker-compose.

Now when I change anything using my editor on the host file system (KUbuntu), it takes a long time (varying from 0s to more than a minute) before changes in the code reflect in the website.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.1'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=my_user
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=my_database
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=my_password
    ports:
      - 9990:3306
    volumes:
      - /home/haaiee/Projects/Docker/decode_appdata/database/mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb
  myapp:
    tty: true
    image: bitnami/laravel:5-debian-9
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_USERNAME=my_user
      - DB_DATABASE=my_database
      - DB_PASSWORD=my_password
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

And in my website when I change

```php
echo 'A'; die();
```

to

```php
echo 'B'; die();
```

when I refresh the webpage (firefox, crtl-F5), it still shows "A".
Only after some time it changes to "B".

Sometimes changes seem to work instantaneously, other times, it can take minutes.

Is there any way to fix this slowness?

Comment: Is there any php page caching enabled ? You can confirm that your container can read the new entries by going inside the container itself and then check the file if it contains the new code.

Comment: Good guess. I got into the container using ```docker exec -it mycontainername bash``` and found out that the file inside the container contains the changed code while the webpage still shows the old value.

Comment: So the issue it seems on the browser side or php side, like you have some cache that needs to be invalidated

Comment: It seems to. I'll report back when I fixed this.